# SQL TRN logs back

Tags: sql-server, backup

i am hoping for some help or guidance , i currently have a database that is in excess close to 1 terabyte, we do a full DB backups once every evening and we run trn log backups every 15mins. this is all working perfectly. however the trn backup files are average between 300mb and 800mb, the issue i have , what is the best and fastest way to back these files up ?

our disaster recovery states we need to restore within one hour

i am currently using a third part tool to backup these large trn files , most of the time it takes a few hours for the backup to complete off the trn files on third party tool due to the size of the trn files.

is there any other or faster way i can backup these trn files( our SQL server is in Azure)

Answer (score 3):

> is there any other or faster way i can backup these trn files( our SQL server is in Azure)

The fastest backup is going to be by scaling your VM, adding Premium or Ultra disks and backing up directly to those disks.

Or you could migrate the database files to Azure Premium Blob storage and use [File-Snapshot Backups for Database Files in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/file-snapshot-backups-for-database-files-in-azure?view=sql-server-ver15).